# Developing with node, npm and vuejs in docker containers?

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm

I would like to avoid polluting my local host machine (running ubuntu) with all the required prerequisites for developing a front end application with node,npm and vuejs.

I am therefor looking for a fast but containerized development environment that I can just turn off/on and revert to baseline fast and easy.

I have found:
https://github.com/aherve/simple-dockerized-dev-env

but its 3 years old and also generates a bunch of errors when I try to run the samples.

Are there more up to date approaches for this with the above mentioned technologies with e.g. docker? Or does VueJS developers generally just install whatever they need on the local host machines?

Comment: How is installing Node "polluting" your system?  That's really the only dependency you need.

Comment: Exactly for this purpose I developed a tool for me and my team. You may take a look at it [here](https://gitlab.com/flexbox/stack/stack), but you're expected to know a thing or two about Docker.

Comment: @AlexKarshin; great I will take a look. @David Maze Some reason are pretty well summarized here: https://hackernoon.com/how-we-happily-dockerized-our-development-environment-part-1-2-b05fd6927a53